# unexpected symbol base in R CMD Check

Tags: r

I am currently running R CMD Check on a package that I am working on, but I get an error message when it checks for the examples of the package. Most of the files seem to be fine and this, which is the second last file that is checked, raises this error when it checks for the examples. I believe `base::assign()` is what R CMD Check does between switching files for example checks. Since this error does not happen for other files, I'm guessing it is a syntax error causing this to show up.

```
checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in â€˜smt-Ex.Râ€™ failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: selComponentTracks
> ### Title: selComponentTracks
> ### Aliases: selComponentTracks
> 
> ### ** Examples
... 349 lines ...
+ ## plot component tracks
+ #plotComponentTrackOverlay(folder=folder3,trackll.sel=trackll.sel)
+ 
+ 
+ 
+ base::assign(".dptime", (proc.time() - get(".ptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), pos = "CheckExEnv")
+ base::cat("selComponentTracks-methods", base::get(".format_ptime", pos = 'CheckExEnv')(get(".dptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), "\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'), append=TRUE, sep="\t")
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"base::assign(".dptime", (proc.time() - get(".ptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), pos = "CheckExEnv")
base"
Execution halted

checking whether package â€˜smtâ€™ can be installed ... WARNING
Found the following significant warnings:
Warning: replacing previous import â€˜stats::lagâ€™ by â€˜dplyr::lagâ€™ when loading â€˜smtâ€™
See â€˜/Users/sys/code/smt.Rcheck/00install.outâ€™ for details.

checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... WARNING
Warning: parse error in file 'smt-Ex.R':
959:1: unexpected symbol
958: cleanEx()
959: nameEx
     ^
```

What could possibly cause this? Has anyone had this error?

Comment: Can you post the original file somewhere or even the whole package in GitHub. With just the error information it is a little bit hard to debug.

Comment: Those lines look like things that `check` added.  Since it thinks its own code contains an `unexpected symbol`, it probably means your example has an open parenthesis or something similar.  Open `smt-Ex.R` in the `smt.Rcheck` directory, and see if your editor (RStudio?) spots the error, or just try to run it all until you get to the syntax error.

Comment: It was the open parenthesis in the example code that was causing this. Thank you  guys for helping out.

Comment: I had the same problem and was first thrown back that no solution was posted. @user2554330 can you write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr** probably an open parenthesis in the examples somewhere.

I'm going to go ahead and post this answer from @user2554330's comment (will happily delete if they come back and post the answer for themselves):

> Those lines look like things that check added. Since it thinks its own code contains an unexpected symbol, it probably means your example has an open parenthesis or something similar. Open `smt-Ex.R` in the `smt.Rcheck` directory, and see if your editor (RStudio?) spots the error, or just try to run it all until you get to the syntax error

In my case I also got a line number reference with the error message: you can also
`source("yourpackage.Rcheck/yourpackage-Ex.R", echo=TRUE)` to help localize the problem.